# Atualizar TextView Android Usando Handler

Tags: android, thread, textview

Comecei Agora a Programar em Android, e estou necessitando atualizar um TextView apos receber uma string de uma conexao Socket. Eu recebo a string corretamente porem o apk fecha dando uma excessão:

> 10-01 11:05:57.470: E/AndroidRuntime(753): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-94

Vi que essa exceção e causada pela atualização da ui por uma thread fora da thread principal, nisso a solução serial usar handler para atualizar a ui, porem nao consegui um exemplo de como fazer isso e gostaria de ajudar para implementar isso no meu codigo:

Buscando na web, encontrei uma forma simples usando uma thread aparte para atualizar a ui,  nos codigods a seguir mostro o que fiz:

Classe AtualizarTexto(thread que tem a funcao de mudar o texto na TextView)

```
package com.example.palioteste;

public class AtualizarTexto implements Runnable {

            private String text;

            public AtualizarTexto(final String text) {
                this.text = text;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {

                MainActivity.textorecebido.setText(text);
            }

        }
```

MainActivity

```
    package com.example.palioteste;

    import java.io.BufferedReader; import java.io.BufferedWriter; import java.io.IOException; import java.io.OutputStreamWriter; import java.net.Socket;
    import android.app.Activity; import android.os.Bundle; import android.view.Menu; import android.view.MenuItem; import android.view.View; import android.view.View.OnClickListener; import android.widget.Button; import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button;
    private TextView textView1;
    static TextView textorecebido;

    @Override   
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);        
        textView1 = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textorecebido = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textorecebido);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
            @Override           
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                textView1.setText("Botao Cliquado");
                abrirSocket rodar = new abrirSocket();
                rodar.execute();            
            }
            });     
        }

    @Override   
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {         
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.        
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);       
        return true;    
    }

    @Override   
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will      
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long       
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.         
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }       
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        } 
}
```

Thread que faz a conexão socket

```
package com.example.palioteste;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.BufferedWriter; 
import java.io.DataOutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter; 
import java.net.Socket; 
import java.util.Arrays;

public class abrirSocket extends AsyncTask { 
private static final String hostname = "192.168.43.127"; 
private static final int portaServidor = 9837; 
int valorconvertido;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, portaServidor);

        //dados enviados para o servidor

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        bw.write("2");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.flush();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        //String retorno =  "Dados Recebidos " + br.readLine(); //retornar ok

        Thread t = new Thread(new AtualizarTexto(br.readLine()));
        t.start();
        // socket.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
    return null;

    }     
}
```

Essa implementação nao deu certo e quero tentar usar handler, porem os exemplos que econtrei não consegui adaptar ao meu codigo e peço ajuda dos membros para isso.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar este método para executar na thread da UI

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textorecebido.setText(text);
        }

    });
```

Ou você pode usar os métodos da Asynctask que também rodas na thread principal como mostra o [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23978570/5749462)

Tenta isso:

```
'@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, portaServidor);

        //dados enviados para o servidor

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new     OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        bw.write("2");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.flush();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    //String retorno =  "Dados Recebidos " + br.readLine(); //retornar ok

        return br.readLine();

       // socket.close();

    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }         return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String resultado) {

    //...
    seuTextview.setText(resultado());
}
```

Comment: Creonilso obrigado pelo rapido contato, me da so um exemplo de implementação desse codigo que me passou, como eu colocaria no codigo!

Comment: Este é um método da Activity, então você terá que chamar dentro de uma Activity ou se for em uma outra classe você terá que passar o contexto(Activity). Então é só copiar este código que te passei e substitui este trecho //textorecebido.setText(text) pelo código que você que que rode na thread principal, não importa em que thread você esteja a UI será atualizada.

Comment: Creonilson, estou apanhando um pouco aqui e ja pesquisei muito, e ainda não consegui resolver. O metodo que me passou ja tinha visto e não tinha conseguido implementar, ainda mais agora que voce disse que entra contexto. Poderia me ajudar so a implementar no codigo, pois pra mim ja servira de grande valia!

Comment: Editei usando o exemplo usando asynctask, testa ai

Comment: Creonilson na verdade eu ja tentei utilizar esse metodo onPostExecute, ele me retorna null, acho que e porque a conexao ja foi fechada no lado servidor logo ele retorna nada. O que eu ja tentei foi:  O metodo da thread separada retorna o valor da conexao porem da a excessao que expliquei. o metodo onPostExecute retorna o valor null, e tentei o onPostUpdate que acho que e o correto, porem nao consegui implementar(nem chega a atualizar a ui), tem algum exemplo de onProgressUpdate

Comment: Você fez isso:  return br.readLine(); e mesmo assim o valor ficava nulo?

Comment: Creonilso, erro de principiante! Retirei o return null e funcionou perfeitamente, agora a ui atualiza sem erros! Muito Obrigado ae pela ajuda!